# Expando Object para Xml

Tags: c#, xml, objetos

Estou utilizando Expando Object (c# VS 2013) para ler um arquivo xml complexo. Preciso agora ler esse Expando Object e transformar novamente em um xml.

Comment: O que você já fez? Tem algum código disponível? Poderia reduzir um pouco o escopo da pergunta para qual o problema que você está tendo na leitura e transformação?

Comment: Felipe boa tarde desculpe a demora em responder. Estou utilizando este código:( http://blog.waseem-sabjee.com/2014/09/14/how-to-convert-an-xml-document-to-a-dynamic-object-in-net/) Ele transforma um xml em uma lista de ExpandoObjects (o que é muito bom pq preciso ler arquivos xml os quais não conheço a estrutura). Porém não consigo transformar novamente Esta Lista Dinamica de ExpandoObjects em XML. Esta bem difícil cara se voce puder por favor me ajudar! Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu já fiz isso:

```
internal class ToXml
    {
        public string GetXml(ExpandoObject obj, XElement rootElement)
        {
            foreach (var keyValue in obj)
            {
                if (keyValue.Value is ExpandoObject)
                {
                    var root = new XElement(keyValue.Key);
                    GetXml(keyValue.Value as ExpandoObject, root);

                    if (rootElement == null)
                        rootElement = root;
                    else
                        rootElement.Add(root);
                }

                if (keyValue.Value is string)
                {
                    var xml = new XElement(keyValue.Key, keyValue.Value);
                    rootElement.Add(xml);
                }
            }
            return rootElement.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Segue o Gist:

https://gist.github.com/thdotnet/7252193

Comment: Thiago muito obrigao pela ajuda! Irei testar hoje a noite tua solução. Mas de maneira geral voce acredita que um ExpandoObject contendo um XML como este aqui posso ser remontatdo por tua solução?                               <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<People>
  <person Id="1">
    <Name>Waseem</Name>
    <Age>25</Age>
  </person>    
  <person Id="2">
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>35</Age>
    <Children>
      <person Id="7">
        <Name>Pedrim</Name>
        <Age>15</Age>
      </person>
    </Children>
  </person>    
</People>

Comment: Basicamente ele tem nós "filhos". No problema que te inspirou não há a presença de nós filhos, "netos" kk. Etc...

Comment: com alguns ajustes é possivel. Mas a ideia é esta.

Comment: Poderia me ajujdar nos ajuses por favor!? Tenho uma classe que me disponibiliza uma lista onde cada tag do xml é um objeto! Como eu poderia trazer isso para xml novamente!?

Comment: Thiago Custodio muito obrigado pela ajuda! Adaptei minha classe para fornecer para a tua um ExpandoObject Funcionou muito bem Obrigado!